# How to write tests first in Java?

Tags: java, testing, tdd

I have read a lot about test-driven design. My project is using tests, but currently they are written after the code has been written, and I am not clear how to do it in the other direction.

Simple example: I have a class `Rectangle`. It has `private` fields `width` and `height` with corresponding getters and setters. Common Java. Now, I want to add a function `getArea()` which returns the product of both, but I want to write the test first.

Of course, I can write a unit test. But it isn’t the case that it fails, but it does not even compile, because there is no `getArea()` function yet. Does that mean that writing the test always already involves changing the productive code to introduce dummys without functionality? Or do I have to write the test in a way that it uses introspection? I don’t like the latter approach, because it makes the code less readable and later refactoring with tools will not discover it and break the test, and I know that we refactor a lot. Also, adding ‘dummys’ may include lots of changes, i.e. if I need additional fields, the database must be changed for Hibernate to continue to work, … that seems way to much productive code changes for me when yet “writing tests only”. What I would like to have is a situation where I can actually only write code inside `src/test/`, not touching `src/main` at all, but without introspection.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Well, TDD does not mean, that you cannot have anything in the production code before writing the test.

For example:

1. You put your method, e.g. `getArea(param1, param2)` in your production code with an empty body.
2. Then you write the test with valid input and your expected result.
3. You run the test and it will fail.
4. Then you change the production code and run the test again.

   - If it still fails: back to the previous step.
   - If it passes, you write the next test.

A quick introduction can be found for example here: [codeutopia -> 5-step-method-to-make-test-driven-development-and-unit-testing-easy](https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/10/10/5-step-method-to-make-test-driven-development-and-unit-testing-easy/)

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like to have is a situation where I can actually only write code inside src/test/, not touching src/main at all, but without introspection.

There isn't, that I have ever seen, a way to write a test with a dependency on a new part of the API, and have that test immediately compile without first extending the API of the test subject.

It's introspection or nothing.

> But it isn’t the case that it fails, but it does not even compile, because there is no getArea() function yet

Historically, writing code that couldn't compile was part of the rhythm of TDD.  Write a little bit of test code, write a little bit of production code, write a little bit of test code, write a little bit of production code, and so on.

Robert Martin describes this as the [nano-cycle of TDD](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/12/17/TheCyclesOfTDD.html)

> ... the goal is always to promote the line by line granularity that I experienced while working with Kent so long ago.

I've abandoned the nano-cycle constraint in my own work.  Perhaps I fail to appreciate it because I've never paired with Kent.

But I'm perfectly happy to write tests that don't compile, and then back fill the production code I need when the test is in a satisfactory state.  That works well for me because I normally work in a development environment that can generate production implementations at just a few key strokes.

Another possibility is to consider a discipline like [TDD as if you meant it](https://cumulative-hypotheses.org/2011/08/30/tdd-as-if-you-meant-it/), which does a lot more of the real work in the test source hierarchy before moving code into the production hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on Android dev quite sometimes, but never fully adopt TDD in Android. However I tried recently to develop my new app with complete TDD. So here is my opinion..

> Does that mean that writing the test always already involves changing the productive code to introduce dummys without functionality?

I think is the yes. As I understand every tests are equivalent to every specs/use cases I have on the software. So writing a fail test first is about the attempt to filling in the requirement specs with test codes. Then when I tried to fill the productive code to pass the just-written TC, I really tried to make it work. After a doing this a while, I was pretty surprised how with my productive code size is very small, but it's able to fill how much of the requirement.

For me personally all the fail TC I wrote before productive code, were actually come from list of questions, which I brainstormed them about the requirement, and I sometimes used it to explore edge cases of requirement.

So the basic workflow is Red - Green - Refactor, which I got from the presentation from Bryan Breecham - https://www.infoq.com/presentations/tdd-lego/

About,

> What I would like to have is a situation where I can actually only write code inside src/test/, not touching src/main at all, but without introspection.

For me I think it's possible, when you write all your productive logic first, then UT plays the roles of fulfilling the requirement. It's just the another way around. So in overall I think TDD is the approach but people may use Unit Test in different purposes, e.g reduce testing time, etc.